# Adding compose to view-based project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add jetpack compose to an existing project that is based on view system.
The problem is that when I add the

```
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.0"
    }
```

to `build.gradle` file and in my project level `build.gradle` file I have `ext.kotlin_version ='1.9.0'`. When I build the application I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/incremental/IncrementalJvmCompilerRunnerKt
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinJvmCompilerArgumentsContributor.contributeArguments(CompilerArgumentsContributor.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Tasks.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask_Decorated.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ...
```

I've changed the version of `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` and `ext.kotlin_version` but I haven't been able to build the project.

Comment: try kotlin compose compiler version 1.5.1